# Why do we define convergence in mean only for integrable random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

**Definition of convergence in mean:** Let $X,X_1,X_2,\dots \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{P})$ be random variables. Then $(X_n)$ converges to $X$ in mean if $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]=0$$
Why do we define convergence in mean only for integrable random variables? Since we take the absolute value, $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]$ would also be defined for non-integrable random variables. (finetly many terms might be $\infty$)

Comment: Because if $X$ is integrable and $X_i$ is not in $L_1(\mathbb{P})$ then neither is $X_i-X$, and so neither is $|X_i-X|$ and hence there is no meaning of the expectation of $|X_i-X|$.

Comment: For $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$, you need at least that $(X_n)$ and $X$ belong to $L^1$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We define convergence in mean only for integrable random variables to avoid situations like: $X_n=X$ for all $n$, $X \geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X]=+\infty$. We have that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]=0$ but this convergence does not come from a normed space.

If you assume $X, X_n \in L^1$ then the convergence is induced by a proper topology over the Banach space $L^1$ and this is a very good thing to have.